# pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError при подключении к localhost

Tags: python, rabbitmq

кто наткнулся на мой вопрос. Я только начал изучать библиотеку pika в Python для работы с очередями в RabbitMQ. И вот первый же код вызывает исключение:

```
import pika


connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
    'localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
```

Исключение следующего вида:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Work/Programming/Code/Envs/parser/my.py", line 5, in <module>
    'localhost'))
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 359, in __init__
    self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 450, in _create_connection
    raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что это может быть?

Comment: Вероятно, у вас на компьютере не запущен никакой брокер очередей сообщений.

Comment: То есть, мне нужно предварительно установить RabbitMQ на своём ПК?

Comment: Да, конечно. Иначе к чему подключаться скрипту?

Comment: Действительно, проблема была именно в этом. Спасибо!